# Select line of text starting with something via Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I need a way to select "h1" everything after "h1" to replace it to nothing using regular expressions. I also need it to work for @import.

I need to change this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
h1 { font-family: 'Special Elite', arial, serif; }
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
h1 { font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', arial, serif; }
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Smythe' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
h1 { font-family: 'Smythe', arial, serif; }
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Smythe);
```

To this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Smythe' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: in which programming/scripting language?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I'm just using search and replace in my text editor.

Comment: @rerun: -1 to you for mindless parroting. Regexes are just fine for most specific HTML; they are just tricky on general HTML. If he has specific cases, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This one should match on the lines you want to keep:

```
(<link.*css'>)
```

And this one should match on the lines you want to delete:

```
(h1 {.*})|(@import.*;)
```

Comment: I don't understand what the big deal is, I just have a 300 line document with a list of HTML data. Why can't we just pretend this is a string?

Comment: @Thomas: HTML is not a Regular language, so using **Regular** Expressions to match it is highly susceptible to breaking.

Comment: No no no! The patterns used in modern text-processing **ARE NOT REGULAR** so they certainly can be used on stuff like this. It’s just nobody stopped calling them regular expressions once they became non-textbook-regular, like with `(.*)\1`, for example. It’s just tricky in the general case is all. It is usually fairly easy in the specific case, so it is just fine to use them.